# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -804 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -804 Incorrect values within SQLDA structure

Tags: php, sql, pdo, firebird

I connected to firebird db from php pdo:

```
<?php
const _QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM R_GETTABLEPROPS(:ATABLEID,:ATABLENAME,:AMASTERTABLEID,:AMASTERTABLENAME,:FLAGS)';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbconf['user'], $dbconf['pass']);
$s = $dbh->prepare(_QUERY);
$s->bindValue(':ATABLENAME', 'LISTW');
$s->execute(); // error here
$s->bindColumn('SQLCOMMAND', $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
```

R_GETTABLEPROPS is:

```
create or alter procedure R_GETTABLEPROPS (
ATABLEID integer,
ATABLENAME varchar(31),
AMASTERTABLEID integer,
AMASTERTABLENAME varchar(31),
FLAGS varchar(10))
returns (
TABLEID integer,
SQLCOMMAND blob sub_type 1 segment size 80
as …
```

Error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -804 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -804 Incorrect values within SQLDA structure

How working with FB blobs in PDO? Queries without blobs is working!

FB client and server is version 2.1.2.

Comment: You are not providing values for the parameters.

Comment: Pardon, added bindValue - be missed in this code.

Comment: You have 5 parameters and you are binding just one!

Comment: @VVS Your query declares 5, so you need to set all 5 of them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is recommend for queries with blobs? For undeclared params PDO don't set is null? But without undeclared params queries without blobs is working.

Comment: I don't know PDO (nor PHP), but drivers usually require you to set all parameters explicitly and given the error that would be the first thing I'd check (the SQLDA structure is related to transfer of parameters).